# Use Route 53 to redirect users to apps after login?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

My situation is rather complicated, but I will try to explain it. I will create an Electron.js and Mobile app that will get used by different companies. The users for each company will connect to an Elastic Beanstalk server application specific for that company.

For instance, Employee A works at company Z. When employee A opens the app, it connects to the server app for company Z.

Employee B works for company Y. When he opens the app, it connects to the server app for company Y. I hope this makes sense.

When an employee logs in to the app they provide their company ID. The app then will contact my own server and database (My own Beanstalk server app and Dynamo DB instance) which returns to the user the endpoint for their company so the app can connect automatically to the right server for their company. Therefore, my server instance would sort of serve as a DNS.

I thought about finding a way to use Route 53, but I don't think it can really help me with my use case, can it?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It's pretty normal to have "dispatch" gateways, you connect to "connect.example.com" login, get an auth token and a target server, for example "node-525.example.com", then the client hops on to that target server. DNS does not cover any of your business logic and does not know about company IDs.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel W. So what you are saying is that my approach is OK? IS it OK then to have my own server for this kind of logic?

Comment: I don't know what's best and it's impossible to judge according to only what has been written in this thread. It seems to me you should build your software first and at a point it grows put the infrastructure on a higher level.

Comment: I don't think this is a suitable use-case for Amazon Route 53. It just sounds like your app should return a URL that they should use.